# Python and regex

Tags: python, regex

i have to parse need string.
Here is command I execute in Linux console:

```
amixer get Master |grep Mono:
```

And get, for example,

```
Mono: Playback 61 [95%] [-3.00dB] [on]
```

Then i test it from python-console:

```
import re,os
print re.search( ur"(?<=\[)[0-9]{1,3}", u"  Mono: Playback 61 [95%] [-3.00dB] [on]" ).group()[0]
```

And get result: 95. It's that, what i need. But if I'll change my script to this:

```
print re.search( ur"(?<=\[)[0-9]{1,3}", str(os.system("amixer get Master |grep Mono:")) ).group()[0]
```

It'll returns None-object. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`os.system()` returns the exit code from the application, not the text output of the application.

You should read up on the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) Python module; it will do what you need.

Comment: If i do: temp = os.system("amixer get Master |grep Mono:") & print temp i get output result. Or i'm wrong?

Comment: The output from the command is going to stdout directly, and not to the 'temp' variable.  Try running that test with 'print "the value of temp is %s characters long, and is: %s" % (len(temp), temp)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `os.system()`, use the `subprocess` module:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen("amixer get Master | grep Mono:", shell = True, stdout = PIPE)
stdout = p.stdout.read()
print re.search( ur"(?<=\[)[0-9]{1,3}", stdout).group()
```

Answer (score 0):

How to run a process and get the output:

http://docs.python.org/library/popen2.html

Comment: Deprecated since version 2.6: This module is obsolete. Use the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Which is linked to in that documentation, but I found popen to be more clear. Thanks for the downvote, though.